# How to make a surface from multiples edge loops?

Tags: modeling, edges

I´ve imported in Blender several edges loops. They have irregular shape and different numbers of vertices. (I've attached the file [here](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?368329-How-to-make-a-surface-from-multiples-edge-loops)).
I want to generate a surface that follows the contour of all edge loops.

I've already tried to convert the object in mesh, and apply Bridge Edge Loops (to create faces and use then with Subdivison Surface). But this tool confuses itself and connects edges far away from themself instead of their neighbors.
An solution would be to apply Bridge in each pair of edge loop, but this would cause too much effort.

Is there any other way for me to contour this problem?

Comment: Try the Loft command from LoopTools instead of Bridge.